# New SSD in 2014 MacBook Pro won't sit properly

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, macbook-pro

I bought an SSD to replace the one that came with my MacBook Pro, mid 2014 retina. It needed an adapter as the connectors were slightly different.

[This](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07J2Q4SWZ) is the SSD:

[This](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07LGTMCCX) is the adapter:

When I plug the SSD into the adapter, it bends upwards:

[image]

When I screwed it down and tested it, it worked without any problems. It still doesn't look like it's sitting right, though:

[image]

Could this be causing any damage to the SSD?

Comment: It looks to me like you need a standoff for the screw to screw into that acts as a spacer between the SSD and the motherboard. It should have been there from the start or in a bag included with the SSD or the adapter. Unfortunately I don't know enough about Macs to say for sure.

Comment: The upwards-pointing SSD is normal in an M.2 slot when not fixated by the screw. The rest appears to be caused by the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

It looks fine to me. As long as the case closes fine, you shouldn't have to worry. If I were you, I would worry about lack of cooling for the SSD module.

Comment: Does the SSD require cooling? The stock SSD did not have any